librouteros: добавить правило брандмауэра в определенную позицию
Как добавить и переместить правило брандмауэра в определенную позицию в Mikrotik с помощью Python и библиотеки librouteros?
Пример кода:
from librouteros import connect
from librouteros.query import Key

# Connect to the MikroTik router
api = connect(
    username='Admin',
    password='Password',
    host='192.168.88.1',
    port=8728
)

def move_firewall_rule(api, rule_id, new_position):
    # Fetch all firewall rules mikrotik
    firewall_rules = api.path('ip', 'firewall', 'filter')

    # Find the rule to be moved
    rule_to_move = None
    for rule in firewall_rules:
        print(rule)
        if rule['.id'] == rule_id:
            rule_to_move = rule
            # print(rule_to_move)
            break

    # sys.exit(1)

    if rule_to_move is None:
        raise ValueError("Rule ID not found")

    # Remove the rule to be moved
    firewall_rules.remove(rule_id)

    # Re-insert the rule at the desired position
    rules_list = list(firewall_rules)
    rules_list.insert(new_position, rule_to_move)

    # Clear all current rules
    for rule in firewall_rules:
        firewall_rules.remove(rule['.id'])

    # Re-add all rules in the new order
    for rule in rules_list:
         firewall_rules.add(**rule)

# Example usage:
move_firewall_rule(api, '*2D', 2)  # Move rule with ID '*2D' to position 2


# Close the connection
api.close()

Программа выдает ошибку:

File "d:\Python\VCS_MSSQL\Mikrotik.py", line 395, in move_firewall_rule
firewall_rules.add(**rule)
librouteros.exceptions.TrapError: unknown parameter


Добавьте строку print(rule) перед строкой, которая даёт ошибку. Так вы узнаете, на какой же параметр он ругается. Попробуйте потом убрать этот параметр. Или разобраться, почему он не валидный. А вообще я не уверен, что там нужно **rule, может там нужно просто rule? И всё-таки покажите, что какого типа эта коллекция: print(type(firewall_rules))

не нужно все правила удалять и добавлять заново.
